# Python JSON Post with headers

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to send a POST request using the python requests library. I've been looking through the answers to the questions here, but I still can't see why my request is failing with a 400 error.

My request looks as follows:

```
url = 'http:/srv01/bill_me'
h = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'JWT eyJ0eX'}
data = {"name": "Chris"}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=h)
status = r.status_code
print(status)
```

The request works fine in Postman, but returns a 400 error when I try to run it through python.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code (although you could use `json=data` and drop the `Content-type` header to have `requests` take care of this for you). Servers are black boxes, perhaps it's the User Agent header or one of the Accept headers that matter here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the header, which needed to be passed through as a dictionary. I changed the code as follows:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Authorization': 'JWT eyJ0eX'})
```